# Native messaging or http

Tags: sockets, web-applications, chrome-native-messaging

I want to be able to execute local shell commands in a web application.

[Chrome Native messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) api seems to be good for that, but as it needs also a service in background, I do not see a real difference with a little http server. 
Is there a real structural difference between them? As I see there is somewhere a socket used as an interface.

Is there any other solutions for that?

Comment: There exists the `rshd` protocol. Not that I want to advice using it, but as it exactly does what you want it might be a point for start investigating from. A more secure successor would be `sshd`.

Comment: ssh, or any other protocol, are in my mind embedded into http in order to bring them in a web context.

Comment: A quick gxxgle revealed this: http://www.serfish.com/console/

Comment: thank you, but for me, it's still http

Comment: They seem to use ajax for this service.

Comment: Yes, and ajax is http:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome Native messaging does not work by calling a running daemon. Instead, it spawns a new process each time `sendMessage` or `connect` is called.

While you can keep the process you opened with `connect` running, if you want to do one-shot commands the `sendMessage` approach is good.

Do note that you will still need a Chrome App or Extension installed to be able to do it, as well as a (separately installed) Native Host module.

Comment: Thank you, I did not figure that there was also the possibility to launch a new process, which can be interesting.